# verilog assertion: Antecedent of the implication never satisfied

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

```
     property p_no_glitch;
    logic data;
        @(in[i]) disable iff (!rst_n)
            (1, data = !in[i]) |=>
        @(posedge clk)
            (in[i] == data);
endproperty : p_no_glitch
CHECK_GLITCH : assert property(p_no_glitch) else $error("%m p_no_glitch");
```

If the module is disabled I get the following message:

**Antecedent of the implication never satisfied**

is there a flag (or any other way) to switch off the above message ?

Comment: Which tool are you using?

Comment: @dwikle I'm using VCS

Comment: Is `i` a genvar or a non-X constant?

Answer (score 0):

the way to go in VCS is  `-assert quiet+quiet1+nopostproc`. Of course it would be better if the SVA 'owner' would add something like `disable iff (!rst_n or !en)`